# Can you do a masters in Canada with 3 years bachelor degree?

Tags: graduate-admissions, canada

Do all Canadian universities require a 4 year degree for masters?

Answer (score 2):

Most Canadian university will admit you to a master if you have an undergraduate degree. This could be a “license” in the European system or a bachelor degree. The reason why universities require a four year degree is because there is no College in the Canadian system ( with the exception of Quebec with its cégep system). Consequently, students enter universities at a young age ( around 17 or 18). If you have completed a bachelor equivalent I would try to apply. School registrar will judge your application based on which education system you are from.

Good luck in your application !

Comment: "This could be a “license” in the European system or a bachelor obtained elsewhere." <- This phrasing could be read as implying that bachelors obtained in Europe are not acceptable. Is that correct?

Comment: I have a 3-year undergraduate degree from Australia. Would that be acceptable for a master?

Comment: 3-year degrees from Europe and Australia are probably acceptable. Focus on the last two sentences ("if you have completed a bachelor equivalent ...")

Comment: I believe that a three year degree from Australia would indeed work. However I am unsure of the specifics. I would definitely apply if I were you. You can also contact the registrar office directly, they will be able to provide clearer information.

Comment: What do you mean there are no colleges in Canada? There certainly are.

Comment: There are colleges in Canada. However, contrary to the Cegep system, from my understanding, going through college  to go to university is not mandatory. https://www.wes.org/advisor-blog/college-and-university-in-canada-what-is-the-difference/